# Python script to generate a word with specific structure and letter combinations

Tags: python, for-loop, syntax-error

I want to write a really short script that will help me generate a random/nonsense word with the following qualities:

-Has 8 letters
-First letter is "A"
-Second and Fourth letters are random letters
-Fifth letter is a vowel
-Sixth and Seventh letters are random letters and are the same
-Eighth letter is a vowel that's not "a"

This is what I have tried so far (using all the info I could find and understand online)

```
firsts = 'A'
seconds = ['a','b','c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
thirds = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'y']
fourths = ['a','b','c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
fifths = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'y']
sixths = sevenths =  ['a','b','c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
eighths = ['e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'y']

print [''.join(first, second, third, fourth, fifth)
       for first in firsts
       for second in seconds
       for third in thirds
       for fourth in fourths
       for fifth in fifths
       for sixth in sixths
       for seventh in sevenths
       for eighth in eighths]
```

However it keeps showing a `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` after the `for` and now I have absolutely no idea how to make this work. If possible please look into this for me, thank you so much!

Comment: `print "something"` is not a valid python 3 statement, you need to do `print("something")`

Comment: I don't think they specified Python 3.  It's a valid Python 2 statement to use print without a traditional call.  If using Python 3 though, definitely an error.  Additionally, the str.join() method wants a single iterable, not multiple values.  You can correct this by handing it a list of the values eg. ''.join(['a', 'b', 'c']) is valid but ''.join('a', 'b', 'c') is not.

Answer (score 0):

So the magic function you need to know about to pick a random letter is `random.choice`. You can pass a list into this function and it will give you a random element from that list. It also works with strings because strings are basically a list of chars. Also to make your life easier, use string module. `string.ascii_lowercase` returns all the letters from a to z in a string so you don't have to type it out. Lastly, you don't use loops to join strings together. Keep it simple. You can just add them together.

```
import string
from random import choice

first = 'A'
second = choice(string.ascii_lowercase)
third = choice(string.ascii_lowercase)
fourth = choice(string.ascii_lowercase)
fifth = choice("aeiou")
sixthSeventh = choice(string.ascii_lowercase)
eighth = choice("eiou")

word = first + second + third + fourth + fifth + sixthSeventh + sixthSeventh + eighth
print(word)
```

Answer (score 0):

This will implement what you describe. You can make the code neater by putting the choices into an overall list rather than have several different variables, but you will have to explicitly deal with the fact that the sixth and seventh letters are the same; they will not be guaranteed to be the same simply because there are the same choices available for each of them.

The list `choices_list` could contain sub-lists per your original code, but as you are choosing single characters it will work equally with strings when using `random.choice` and this also makes the code a bit neater.

```
import random

choices_list = [
    'A',
    'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz',
    'aeiouy',
    'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz',
    'aeiouy',
    'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz',
    'eiouy'
    ]

letters = [random.choice(choices) for choices in choices_list]

word = ''.join(letters[:6] + letters[5:])  # here the 6th letter gets repeated

print(word)
```

Some example outputs:

```
Alaeovve
Aievellu
Ategiwwo
Aeuzykko
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import random
sixth=random.choice(sixths)
s='A'+random.choice(seconds)+random.choice(thirds)+random.choice(fourths)+random.choice(fifths)+sixth+sixth+random.choice(eighths)
print(s)
```

Output:

```
Awixonno
Ahiwojjy
etc
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several things to consider. First, the `str.join()` method takes in an iterable (e.g. a `list`), not a bunch of individual elements. Doing

```py
''.join([first, second, third, fourth, fifth])
```

fixes the program in this respect. If you are using Python 3, `print()` is a function, and so you should add parentheses around the entire list comprehension.

With the syntax out of the way, let's get to a more interesting problem: Your program constructs every (82255680 !) possible word. This takes a long time and memory. What you want is probably to just pick *one*. You can of course do this by first constructing all, then picking one at random. It's far cheaper though to pick one letter from each of `firsts`, `seconds`, etc. at random and then collecting these. All together then:

```py
import random
  
firsts = ['A']
seconds = ['a','b','c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
thirds = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'y']
fourths = ['a','b','c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
fifths = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'y']
sixths = sevenths =  ['a','b','c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
eighths = ['e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'y']

result = ''.join([
    random.choice(firsts),
    random.choice(seconds),
    random.choice(thirds),
    random.choice(fourths),
    random.choice(fifths),
    random.choice(sixths),
    random.choice(sevenths),
    random.choice(eighths),
])
print(result)
```

To improve the code from here, try to:

1. Find a way to generate the "data" in a neater way than writing it out explicitly. As an example:

```py
import string
seconds = list(string.ascii_lowercase)  # you don't even need list()!
```

2. Instead of having a separate variable `firsts`, `seconds`, etc., collect these into a single variable, e.g. a single `list` containing each original `list` as a single `str` with all characters included.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the syntax fix:

```
print(["".join([first, second, third]) 
 for first in firsts 
 for second in seconds 
 for third in thirds])
```

This method might take up a lot of memory.